# What is the difference between const and immutable in D?

Tags: constants, d, immutability

What is the difference between the `const` and `immutable` type qualifiers in D?

Comment: You can read about immutablity on this link http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/const_and_immutable.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something that is `const` cannot be mutated via that reference but could be mutated by a mutable reference to the same data. Something that is `immutable` can't be mutated by *any* reference to that data. So, if you have

```
const C c = foo();
```

then you know that you cannot mutate the object referred to by `c` through `c`, but other references to the object referred to by `c` may exist in your code, and if they're mutable, they could mutate it and therefore change what `c` sees. But if you have

```
immutable C c = foo();
```

then you know that it's not possible for the object referred to by `c` to change. Once an `immutable` object has been constructed, it's illegal for it to be mutated, and unless you subvert the type system via casting, it's not even possible to have a mutable reference to an `immutable` object. And since `immutable` objects can be put into read-only memory if the compiler chooses to, you could actually get segfaults and the like if you ever tried to cast away `immutable` and mutate the object. The same goes for `const`, since a `const` reference could actually refer to an `immutable` object. Casting away either `const` or `immutable` and then mutating the then mutable object is undefined behavior and should basically never be done.

And since an `immutable` object can never be mutated even by another reference, reading an `immutable` object from multiple threads is completely thread-safe. So, `immutable` objects are implicitly shared across threads, whereas everything else which isn't explicitly marked with `shared` is considered thread-local. `immutable` also provides better optimization opportunities to the compiler than `const` does, because it's guaranteed to never change, whereas a `const` object can change through another reference to the same data.

For value types, there isn't really much difference between `const` and `immutable` (since you can't have mutable references to non-mutable value types), but for reference types, there is a significant difference.

Comment: Thanks for a very instructive answer. Which one do D developers normally use for value types?

Comment: @user763305 At the moment, I can't think of any technical reason to prefer one over the other, and I don't know what the average D developer chooses to use. Personally, I choose `immutable`, because then it's clear that it can't be mutated without having to know that it's a value type, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: But surely casting away `immutable` from a character of a `string` is perfectly ok?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk If you're accessing a single `char` in a `string`, then there's no need to cast away immutable, because it's a value type, and assigning it to anything will copy it. What's dangerous is casting away `const` or `immutable` for a reference type (like a class object or an array or string). And I don't believe that you can mutate any elements in a string without casting the whole string to `char[]`, because casting a single element in an attempt assign to it would result in an rvalue, not an lvalue, so the assignment wouldn't work regardless of mutability.

Answer (score 14):

When you declare something as `const`, you promise that you won't modify it. When something is declared as `immutable`, you get promised that it won't get modified somewhere else(and ofcourse, you can't modify it either)

Answer (score 2):

They are different in that `immutable` data, could actually placed in **read-only sections** of memory, and hence, any attempts to modify the data it **will** fail.

Something declared `const` (and not immutable) on the other hand exists in the r/w section and the value **can still be changed** via a different non-const reference to it.

So, "const-ness" can be bypassed in such a case, while immutability cannot.

([Reference](http://dlang.org/const3.html))

Comment: This isn't completely correct as `const` data can actually be `immutable` originally. So `const` data may also be in read-only sections as `immutable` data casts implicitly to `const`.

Comment: @yaz Agreed. I wasn't talking about immutable being cast to const in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A variable declared of type `const` can accept a mutable value or immutable value. This definition is relevant for referenced types like arrays and objects or pointers. It would typically be used for function arguments. So in D const is a kind of wildcard attribute for mutable and immutable values.

It doesn't have much sense for values that are copied with an assignment like a char, int or float.

The concept of const and immutable is very different from the one found in C and C++. I was very confused by this.