# Safely Investigating Individual Bytes of a String in D

Tags: arrays, string, casting, byte, d

Why is `cast`ing a `string` to an `ubyte[]` force to be unsafe in D?

And why is the same case using `std.conv:to` unsafe and nothrow?

I can very well understand that the opposite (casting `ubyte[]` to UTF-8) must be unsafe and throw but not this case?

Why can't I safely investigate these individual bytes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@safe` has *nothing* to do with UTF-8 vs ASCII. `@safe` has everything to do with memory safety. It's guaranteeing stuff like that you won't be operating on released or corrupt memory. Many types of casts are considered `@system` and unsafe, because they risk doing stuff that violates memory safety, and it requires that the programmer verify that the cast doesn't actually violate memory safety and mark the function as `@trusted` in order to tell the compiler that it's actually safe, making it useable in `@safe` code.

As for casting `string` to `ubyte[]`, casting away `immutable` like that is circumventing the type system. It makes it so that *you* have to guarantee that your code isn't mutating the data, and if you don't, you've violated the compiler's guarantees, and you're going to have bugs. I'd suggest looking at

[What is the difference between const and immutable in D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115900/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-immutable-in-d/17119659#17119659)

[Logical const in D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219600/logical-const-in-d/4328450#4328450)

To make a long story short, don't cast away `const` or `immutable` unless you really need to, and you know what you're doing.

`std.conv.to` will `dup` an array if it has to in order to do a conversion, so `to!(ubyte[])("hello world")` is going to result in a new `ubyte[]` with the same values as `"hello world"`, but it won't be the same array, and therefore won't violate the type system. If it had been `to!(immutable(ubyte)[])("hello world")`, then it could cast the array, but it can't as long as you're converting to a mutable array.

As for `to!(ubyte[])("hello world")` being `@system` and `nothrow`, that's an implementation issue. It should definitely be possible for it to be `@safe`, and I think that it can be `nothrow`, since it shouldn't need to decode the characters, but the underlying implementation doesn't support that, likely because much of the low level stuff that Phobos uses doesn't support `@safe`, `pure`, or `nothrow` yet, even when it should. The situation with that is improving (e.g. with dmd 2.064, `format` can now be `pure` under some circumstances), but there's still quite a ways to go.

As for "investigating the individual bytes," I don't see why you need to do any conversion at all. Just iterate over the `string`'s elements. They're `char`, which is exactly the same size and signedness as `ubyte`. But if you really want to operate on the `string` as an array of `ubyte` without having to allocate, then just cast to the same constness as `string` - e.g.

```
auto arr = cast(immutable(ubyte)[])"hello world";
```

or

```
auto arr = to!(immutable(ubyte)[])("hello world");
```

Comment: Casting isn't necessarily unsafe, only certain kinds are disallowed. I think casting pointer types is always considered @system, but going between integer types (which includes char, byte, etc.) I'm pretty sure is always allowed.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe That's true, though it's frequently true that casts are unsafe (particularly with generic code). It should come down to which casts the compiler can guarantee memory safety for and which it can't. Regardless, I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

string -> ubyte is disallowed in safe mode because that is casting away the immutability of string. `cast(immutable(ubyte)[]) some_string` is permitted. You can also look at the bytes of a string by doing `foreach(char c; some_string) { /* look at c */ }`.

`to!(ubyte[])(some_string)` worked for me, even in safe mode, though it can throw. The reason is because the appender helper function in std.array isn't properly marked nothrow; a phobos bug. If you add nothrow to std/array.d line 2662 (in dmd 2.064.2) it will then compile as nothrow too.

Answer (score 2):

See also [std.string.representation](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html#.representation).

Comment: Ahh, that's what I wanted.