# const immutable BigInt and range.join in D

Tags: d

I'm learning D and I have been playing with more and more functions and tools defined in phobos. I came across two functions that don't work when the parameters are const or immutable.

```
BigInt i = "42", j = "42";
writeln(i + j);
// This works, except when I add a const/immutable qualifier to i and j
// When const: main.d(23): Error: incompatible types for ((i) + (j)): 'const(BigInt)' and 'const(BigInt)'
// When immutable: main.d(23): Error: incompatible types for ((i) + (j)): 'immutable(BigInt)' and 'immutable(BigInt)'
```

The same happens with the std.array.join function.

```
int[] arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
int[] arr2 = [5, 6];
writeln(join([arr1, arr2]));
// Again, the const and immutable errors are almost identical
// main.d(28): Error: template std.array.join(RoR, R)(RoR ror, R sep) if (isInputRange!RoR && isInputRange!(ElementType!RoR) && isInputRange!R && is(Unqual!(ElementType!(ElementType!RoR)) == Unqual!(ElementType!R))) cannot deduce template function from argument types !()(const(int[])[])
```

This is quite surprising to me. I have a C++ background so I usually write const everywhere, but it seems I can't do it in D.

As a D "user", I see that as a bug. Can someone explain me why this is not a bug and how I should call these functions with const/immutable data? Thanks.

Comment: I think that it is z bug that they didn't make `opBinary(op)` const, they are `pure` but I think that doesn't mean they are `const`

Comment: Regarding BigInt, it is a bug and a pull request has already been made against it. Check https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/pull/1679. Most probably, the next release will have this work.

Comment: @ratchetfreak `const` and `pure` are completely orthogonal concepts in D. You can mutate stuff as much as you want in a `pure` function. You just can't access any global or `static` variables which can be mutated once they're initialized (you're restricted to what's passed into the function and to constants which are global or static). D's `pure` is a key building block in functional purity but really has very little to do with functional purity on its own. I'd advise reading this article on it: http://klickverbot.at/blog/2012/05/purity-in-d/

Comment: @JonathanMDavis then there's the problem the opBinaries in BigInt aren't const while they should be

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes, unless the functions that you're trying to use on `BigInt` are `const` or `inout`, then they won't work with `const`, regardless of how they're implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I should say that D's `const` is very different from C++'s `const`. Like C++, ideally you'd mark as much with it as possible, but unlike with C++, there are serious consequences to marking something `const` in D.

In D, `const` is transitive, so it affects the entire type, not just the top level, and unlike in C++, you can't mutate it by casting it away or by using `mutable` (it's undefined behavior and will cause serious bugs if you try to cast away `const` from an object and then mutate it). The result of those two things is that there are many places where you just can't use `const` in D without making it impossible to do certain things.

D's `const` provides real, solid guarantees that you can't mutate the object through that reference in any way, shape or form, whereas C++'s `const` just makes it so that you can't mutate anything which is `const` by accident, but you can easily cast away `const` and mutate the object (with defined behavior), or pieces of the object could be changed internally by `const` functions thanks to `mutable`. It's also trivial in C++ to return a mutable reference to the internals of a class from a `const` function even without casting or `mutable` (e.g. returning `vector<int*>` from a `const` function - the `vector` can't be mutated but everything it refers to can be). None of those are possible in D, as D guarantees full transitive `const`, and providing those guarantees makes it so that any circumstance where you need to get at something mutable from something `const` isn't going to work unless you create an entirely new copy of it.

You should probably read over the answers to these questions:

[Logical const in D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219600/logical-const-in-d/4328450)

[What is the difference between const and immutable in D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115900/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-immutable-in-d/17119659)

So, if you're slapping `const` on everything in D, you'll find that some things just won't work. Using `const` as much as you can is great for the same reasons that it is in C++, but the cost is much higher, so you have to be more restrictive about what you mark with `const`.

Now, as to your specific issue here. `BigInt` is *supposed* to work with `const` and `immutable` but does not currently. There are a [few](https://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=11148) [open](https://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4301) [bugs](https://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=11188) on the issue. I believe that a lot of the problem stems from the fact that `BigInt` uses [COW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) internally, and that doesn't play nicely with `const` or `immutable`. Fortunately, there's a [pull request on github](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/pull/1679) at the moment which fixes at least some of the problems, so I expect that `BigInt` will work with `const` and `immutable` in the near future, but for the moment, you can't.

As for `join`, your example compiles just fine, so you copied your code wrong. There is no `const` in your example. Perhaps you meant

```
const int[] arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const int[] arr2 = [5, 6];
writeln(join([arr1, arr2]));
```

And *that* doesn't compile. And that's because you aren't passing a valid range of ranges to `join`. The type that you'd be passing to `join` in that case would be `const(int[])[]`. The outer array is mutable, so it's fine, but the inner ones - the ranges that you're trying to join together - are `const`, and nothing which is `const` can be a valid range, and that's because `popFront` won't work. For something to be a valid input range, this code must compile for it (and this is taken from inside of `std.range.isInputRange`).

```
    R r = void;       // can define a range object
    if (r.empty) {}   // can test for empty
    r.popFront();     // can invoke popFront()
    auto h = r.front; // can get the front of the range
```

`const(int[])` won't work with `popFront` as `isInputRange` requires. e.g.

```
const int[] arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.popFront();
```

won't compile, so `isInputRange` is `false`, and `join` won't compile with it.

Now, fortunately, arrays are a bit special in that the compiler understands them, so the compiler knows that it's perfectly legit to turn `const(int[])` into `const(int)[]` when you slice it. That is, it knows that giving you a tail-const slice won't be able to affect the original array (because the result is a new array, and while the elements are shared between the arrays, they're all `const`, so they still can't be mutated). So, the type of `arr[]` would be `const(int)[]` instead of `const(int[])`, and the type of `[arr1[], arr2[]]` is `const(int)[][]`, which will work with `join`. So, you can do

```
const int[] arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const int[] arr2 = [5, 6];
writeln(join([arr1[], arr2[]]));
```

and your code will work just fine. However, that's just because you're using arrays. If you were dealing with user-defined ranges, the moment you made one of them `const`, you'd be stuck. This code won't compile

```
const arr1 = filter!"true"([1, 2, 3, 4]);
const arr2 = filter!"true"([5, 6]);
writeln(join([arr1[], arr2[]]));
```

And that's because the compiler doesn't know that it can safely get a tail-const slice from a ser-defined type. It needs to know that it can convert `const MyRange!E` to `MyRange!(const E)` and have the proper semantics. And it can't know that, because those are two different template instantiations, and they could have completely different internals. The programmer writing `MyRange` would have to be able to write `opSlice` such that it returns `MyRange(const E)` when the type is `const MyRange!E` or `const MyRange!(const E)`, and that's actually hard to do (if nothing else, it very easily results in recursive template instantiations). Some clever use of `static if` and `alias this` should make it possible, but it's hard enough to do that pretty much no one does it right now. It's an open question as to how we're going to make it sane for user-defined types to make `opSlice` return a tail-const range. And until that question is solved, `const` and ranges just don't mix, because as soon as you get a `const` range, there's no way to get a tail-const slice of it which could have `popFront` called on it. So, once your range is `const`, it's `const`.

Arrays are special, since they're built-in, so you can get away with using `const` with them as long as you slice them at the appropriate times (and the fact that templates are instantiated with their slice type rather than their original type helps), but in general, if you're using a range, just assume that you can't make it `const`. Hopefully, that changes someday, but for now, that's the way that it is.

Comment: "nothing which is `const` can be a valid range" Ah, `popFront`, of course! Thanks :) I thought that slicing (`arr1[]`) was only usefull to apply an operation to all the elements, like `arr1[] += 2;` Now you tell me that it can change the constantness of an array. Does it copy the array? Does `[]` do something else? If so, do you have any interesting link on this subject?

Comment: @Nil Actually, `arr[] += 2` isn't slicing at all. That applies a vector operation, much as the syntax is similar. Slicing an array results in an array which refers to the same elements (e.g. `arr[]`) or in subset of them if indices are given (e.g. `arr[2 .. 5]` or `arr[9 .. $]`). No copying takes place. I would advise reading this article on arrays: http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html