# Cartesian product of immutable ranges

Tags: d, phobos

Why can't we compute the cartesian product of two immutable ranges ?

The following code :

```
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm;

void main() {

    immutable int[] B = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
    immutable int[] C = [ 4, 5, 6 ];
    auto BC = cartesianProduct(B, C);

    writeln(BC);
}
```

Throws :

```
/usr/include/dmd/phobos/std/range.d(4199): Error: cannot modify struct result._ranges_field_1 Repeat!(immutable(int)) with immutable members
/usr/include/dmd/phobos/std/range.d(4503): Error: template instance std.range.Zip!(immutable(int)[], Repeat!(immutable(int))) error instantiating
/usr/include/dmd/phobos/std/algorithm.d(11674):        instantiated from here: zip!(immutable(int)[], Repeat!(immutable(int)))
laurent_test.d(8):        instantiated from here: cartesianProduct!(immutable(int)[], immutable(int)[])
/usr/include/dmd/phobos/std/algorithm.d(11674): Error: template instance std.range.zip!(immutable(int)[], Repeat!(immutable(int))) error instantiating
laurent_test.d(8):        instantiated from here: cartesianProduct!(immutable(int)[], immutable(int)[])
laurent_test.d(8): Error: template instance std.algorithm.cartesianProduct!(immutable(int)[], immutable(int)[]) error instantiating
```

Futhermore, if the second *but the first* immutable is removed it works.

According to the phobos implementation, one of the range as to be an inputRange and the other a forwardRange. Why such template constraints ?

Comment: Note that what people often intend are mutable arrays of immutable members, e.g. `immutable(int)[]`. `immutable int[]` is equivalent to `immutable(int[])`, which is more restrictive than the first type. Can't say that it applies to your problem, especially since it doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm definitely not an expert in D, but I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034517/const-immutable-bigint-and-range-join-in-d) last year and this [answer from Jonathan M Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035795/912757) was excellent.

TL;DR: A range can't be immutable because it would't respect the 4 rules:

```
R r = void;       // can define a range object
if (r.empty) {}   // can test for empty
r.popFront();     // can invoke popFront()
auto h = r.front; // can get the front of the range
```

Can you guess the culprint? `popFront`

Comment: Indeed, the static assert(isForwardRange!(typeof(B))) failed.

Comment: I am sorry I don't accept this answer because I don't understand everything. For example the chain () function works, because it uses the Unqual template. Computing the cartesian product does'nt require popFront isn't it ? Why do we need an input and a forward range ?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is the problem here, since even slicing it explicitly, which should remove the top-level immutable, doesn't work. Looks like somewhere in here it is trying to assign to the type internally and that's what is tripping it up; I'm leaning toward it being a latent bug in the implementation but haven't checked the source yet.