# What is the difference between immutable and const member functions?

Tags: constants, d, immutability, member-functions, storage-class-specifier

The D programming language reference shows two examples in the [Declarations](http://dlang.org/spec/declaration.html) and [Type Qualifiers](https://dlang.org/spec/const3.html) section, so these are both possible:

```d
struct S
{
    int method() const
    {
        //const stuff
    }
}

struct S
{
    int method() immutable
    {
        //immutable stuff
    }
}
```

From the docs:

> Const member functions are functions that are not allowed to change any part of the object through the member function's this reference.

And:

> Immutable member functions are guaranteed that the object and anything referred to by the this reference is immutable.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115900/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-immutable-in-d), but all the answers are talking about data types, not storage classes. Same goes for the [D const FAQ](https://dlang.org/const-faq.html), even though it's an interesting read.

So what is the difference between the two definitions above? Are there expressions that can replace `//const stuff` and be legal but not `//immutable stuff`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`immutable` methods may only be called on `immutable` objects. They can work with the guarantee* that their object (`this`) will not change, ever.

`const` methods may be called on `const`, `immutable`, or mutable objects. They guarantee that they themselves will not change their object, but other references may change the object.

I'd go with `const` unless you have a good reason to need `immutable`, as `const` functions are callable with all three mutability storage classes.

---

* At the type system level, anyway. Mutating an immutable object is possible, but causes undefined behavior.